# Is Language $ L = \{ww^{R} \in \{a,b,c\}^{*} : |w|_{a} \not\equiv |w|_{b} $ and $ |w|_{b} \not\equiv |w|_{c} \} $ context free?

Tags: complexity-theory, formal-languages, regular-languages, context-free, pumping-lemma

$ L = \{ww^{R}  \in \{a,b,c\}^{*} : |w|_{a} \not\equiv |w|_{b} $  and $ |w|_{b} \not\equiv |w|_{c} \} $

I would use the Ogden pumping lemma. Assumption $n < m$ where $n$ is a number from lemma. My selected word : $ a ^ {m! + m} c ^ {m! + m} b ^ {m} b ^ {m} c ^ {m! + m} a ^ {m! + m} $ where the first $ b ^ {m} $ are the distinguished characters.

It seems to me that it isn't possible to pump this word in any way possible so it isn't contex-free langauge. Have I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right that $L$ is not context-free. You have found the nice word to test the pumping lemma as well.

Intuitively we cannot recognize $L$ using a pushdown automaton as the number of $b$'s has to be used twice, once in comparing against the number of $a$'s and once in comparing against the number of $c$'s. However, that is far from a proper proof.

We can just use [the standard pumping lemma for context-free language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages) for a rigorous proof.

For the sake of contradiction, let $p>0$ be a pumping length for $L$. Consider word $t=a ^ {p!+p} c ^ {p!+p} b ^ {p} b ^ {p} c ^ {p!+p} a ^ {p!+p} $, which is basically the same word you have chosen. Let $t=uvwxy$, where $|vx|\geq 1$, $|vwx|\leq p$, and $uv^nwx^ny\in L$ for all $n\ge0$.

There are two cases.

- $vwx$ contains at least one letter other than $b$.
  Then $vwx$ must be completely inside either the front half of $t$ or the back half of $t$ since $|vwx|\le p$ and all $a$s and $bs$ in $t$ are at least $p$ letters away from the center. WLOG assume $vwx$ is in the back half of $t$. Let $s=uwy=uv^0wx^0y$, which is a word that starts with some number of none-$b$ letters, followed by some $b$s, followed by less number of none-$b$ letters. $s$ cannot be a palindrome.
- $vwx$ contains only $b$s.
  Let $vx=b^k$, where $k\le p$. Let $n=\dfrac{2p!}{k}+1$. Then let $s=uv^nwx^ny= a ^ {p!+p} c ^ {p!+p} b ^ {p!+p} b ^ {p!+p} c ^ {p!+p} a ^ {p!+p}\not\in L\,.$

In all cases, we can pump $t$ to $s\not\in L$, which contradicts that $p$ is a pumping length of $L$. This contradiction shows $L$ is not context-free.

---

Here are two related exercises.

**Exercise 1**. Show the following language is not context-free.
$$ L = \{w  \in \{a,b,c\}^{*} : |w|_{a} > |w|_{b}\text{ and } |w|_{a} > |w|_{c} \}\,. $$

**Exercise 2**. Show the following language is not context-free. (Hint, Ogden's lemma.)
$$ L = \{w  \in \{a,b,c\}^{*} : |w|_{a} \not=|w|_{b}\text{ and } |w|_{a} \not= |w|_{c} \}\,. $$